# Batch - Echo value of variables in another variable?

Tags: variables, batch-file, set

On the Batch-file I am currently working on, I've encountered a small problem. I have a file called `Dimensions(number from 1-5, defined in a for /l loop).txt` in which contains `%b1%%b2%%b3%%b4%%b5%`. I want to be able to `echo` the values of `%b1%%b2%%b3%%b4%%b5%` through a value, for example being `string1` which was set via `set /p string1=<Dimensions1.txt`.

In other words, I want to be able to use `echo %string1%` (which consist of 5 variables), and have those variable's values echo'd. If this doesn't make sense, here's my code sample;

```
for /l %%g in (1,1,%height%) do (
set /p line%%g=<Dimensions%%g.txt
)
:Nextstep
echo Use WASD to move over the map, and select tiles.
for /l %%h in (1,1,%height%) do (
pause
echo %line1%
echo %%line%%h%%
)
```

While Dimensions1.txt (The first which should be set into `%line1%`) looks like this;

```
%b1%%b2%%b3%%b4%%b5%
```

In `echo %%line%%h%%`, the %%'s should cancel eachother out, excluding `%%h` which should be `1`. Desired to be; `%line1%` (which is, as I said, `%b1%%b2% etc...`.), however printing their values.

Right now all I get is `%line1%`. I've tried other methods such as, as someone commented on my last (somewhat similar) question, to do `set percent=%%` (with `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansions`) and use !percent! on the outsides, however that, neither, gave me the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use delayed expansion here and also CALL expansion.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
...
for /l %%h in (1,1,%height%) do (
    call echo !line%%h!
)
```

First the %%h will expand, so you get
`call echo !line1!`

Then the delayed expansion will be done
`call echo %b1%%b2%%b3%%b4%%b5%`

Then the `call` will expand the percent variables to their content

**If the speed is relevant here, you should avoid the `call` expansion at all.**
See also [Dostips:CALL me, or better avoid call](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1947)

Then you could use delayed expansion instead, so in your file you would place `!b1!!b2!!b3!!b4!!b5!`.
And to expand this you could use a nested FOR-Loop

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
...
for /l %%h in (1,1,%height%) do (
    set "line=!line%%h!"
    FOR /F "delims=" %%L in ("!line!") DO echo %%L
)
```

In this case the content of the variable line is `!b1!!b2!!b3!!b4!!b5!`.
Then in the For-Loop paramter %%L will be also `!b1!!b2!!b3!!b4!!b5!`.
But this will expand in the echo statement, as the delayed expansion phase is later than the FOR-Parameter expansion phase.

Even it looks more complicated, it's much faster

Comment: Seems I was mis-using the `!`'s, let alone not using Call. This works like a charm, thank you very much!